# Will cron job for creating db affect the user?

Tags: mysql, cron

I have a website where I need to create a temporary database table which recreates every 5 hours. It takes about 0.5 sec to complete the action.

Site analytics shows about 5 hits / Second. This figure may gradually increase.

### Question

The cron job empties the db and the recreates it. Does it mean, while someone is accessing a page which populates data based on the temporary db while its active under the cron job, he may get no data found or incomplete data?
Or 
This scenario is taken care of by Mysql due to locking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of dropping and recreating, you might to create first under a temporary name, populate and then drop the old one while renaming the new one.

Additionally, you should either make your web app fit for retrying if the table was not found in order to cope with the small time window where the table is not here, or operate on a view instead of renaming tables.

Answer (score 1):

From my tests, if one MySQWL client attempts to drop a database while another client has one of its tables locked, the client will wait until the tasble is unlocked.

However the client dropping the database cannot itself hold a lock on any of the database's tables either.  So depending on what you are doing, you may need to use some other method to serialise requests and so on.  For example, if the job needs to drop and re-create the database, create the table(s) and populate them before other clients use them, table locking will be a problem because there won't always be a table to lock.

Consider using explicit locking using [`get_lock()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock) to coordinate operations on the "temporary" database.

Also consider rethinking your strategy.  Dropping and re-creating entire databases on a regular basis is not a common practice.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I also realize that dropping and recreating is not a good practice. What batter way can i solve this? My intermediate DB is used for Main Menu, appearing on every page.

Answer (score 0):

as I know, when you lock the table, others couldn't access that table unless you unlock it, but other connections will only be waiting until 0.5 seconds later, so your users may have to wait for extra 0.5 seconds when you recreate the table.

don't worry about no data, only sometime delay.